# Changing image on jquery toggle function

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to change an image using the replace command when toggling using jquery..basically showing a downward arrrow which becomes an upward arrow after the content is revealed.  This following code works except the downward arrow doesn't get replaced.

```
<img src="/images/arrow_down.png" id="#1" class="nav-toggle">
<div id="1" style="display:none">some content</div>
```

and here is the jquery code

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('id');
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {

            } else {
                toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("down", "up");
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: IDs shouldn't start with numbers.

Comment: why you used the # in id is there any reason using this ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning it back to the src, try:

```
toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("down", "up"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Less code is better.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="#arrow-toggle">
    <img src="/images/arrow_down.png">
    <img src="/images/arrow_up.png" class="up" style="display: none;">
</a>
<div id="content" style="display:none">some content</div>
```

jQuery

```
(function($) { 

    $('#arrow-toggle').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('img:visible', this).hide().siblings().show();
        $('#content').toggle($('img:visible').is('.up'));
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like;

```
jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('id');
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("image_2.jpg", "image_1.jpg"));
            } else {
                toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("image_1.jpg", "image_2.jpg"));
            }
        });
    });
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/kYXcu/)*** is a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [jQuery.UI.toggleSwitch()](http://taitems.github.com/UX-Lab/ToggleSwitch/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img src="/images/arrow_down.png" id="#1" class="nav-toggle">
<div id="1" style="display:none">some content</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
    var t = $(this);
    var imgSrc = t.attr('src');
    var divId = t.attr('id');
    $(divId).toggle('slow', function() {
      if (imgSrc === '/images/arrow_down.png') {
        t.attr({'src' : '/images/arrow_up.png'});
      } else {
        t.attr({'src' :'/images/arrow_down.png'});
      }
     });
  });
});
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#id").slideToggle(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                $("div#id").css({'background-image':'url(css/img/nav_plus.gif)'});
            } else {
                $("div#id").css({'background-image':'url(css/img/nav_minus.gif)'});
            }
        });
```

another easy solution may be can help someone ;)