# Image not changing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am retrieving images from database and want them to change on on-click event.

**on click event :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chnj').onclick(function () {
           $('#rotatetest').toggle();
         });
    });
</script>
```

**div containing images :**

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="rotatetest">

  <asp:Repeater ID="rptrTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push2 test" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <img class=" image img-circle" height="200" width="200" src="<%# Eval(" PhotoPath")
           %>" style="border:10px solid white;" id="img" />
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

  <div style="margin-top:50px;text-align:left;">
    <h3 style="color:white;font-family:Pristina;">
      <%# Eval("Description") %>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The onclick should by triggered when glyphicon within span element having class chnj is clicked.

Comment: Could you please add more information.

Comment: Your click method is not a valid jQuery method, try using either `.on()` or `.click()`. And taking your function at face value, all it will do, once the trigger element is clicked on, is toggle the visibility of `#rotatetest`

Comment: I think you will want to be using click() instead of onclick: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 3):

There's no `onclick` event in jquery, it should be `click` :

```
$('.chnj').click(function () {
     $('#rotatetest').toggle();
});
```

You could also use event delegation `on()` :

```
$('body').on('click', '.chnj', function () {
    $('#rotatetest').toggle();
});
```

The `onclick` could be used as inline event :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Or in vanilla js :

```
myElement.onclick=function(){ myScript };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you need use `.click`, and for multiple event you can use `on` instead of `"onclick"`. because `onclick` use in javascript code.

Comment: The toggle function does not change the images on click event rather it gives a bluring effect. I need to change images on the onclick event. I tried changing src attribute but that is not a feasible option for dynamic

Comment: May be this link help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355799/changing-image-on-jquery-toggle-function

Comment: what if i want to change images using src attribute in jquery. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
$("#imgtwo, #imgthree,#imgfour").hide();
 $(".chnj").click(function () {
   var src = $('#imgone').attr('src');
 //chnj img1 to img2
 if (src == 'Images/Support.jpg') {
 //chnj img2 to img3
   $("#img").attr("src", "Images/Prodbac1.jpg"); }
 else if (src == "Images/Prodbac1.jpg")  {
   $("#img").attr("src", "Images/quality.jpg");}
else {
$("#img").attr("src", "Images/slide.jpg");
 }
});
 });
    </script>

Comment: please post in fiddle