# change style list image onclick + to -

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everybody I hope you are all fine
 please help me to resolve this problem,I am confused with this, 
when  "onclick" I want that the + become - like this attached image.
remember that that + and - are images named image 'puceplus.png' and 'pucemoins.png'

```css
#ulist li:before {
    content: url('puceplus.png');
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ulist">
            <li  onclick="hideshow('usublist1')">
                Gestion des données clients
                <ul id="usublist1" style="display:none;" class="sublist">
                    <li >
                       Centraliser vos données clients et éviter les redondances
                      </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What attached image? Can you include all relevant information _in the question itself_?

Comment: Add CSS classes for both types (plus & minus) and add/remove class on click.

Comment: .. or add _one_ class for an “active” state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing image on jquery toggle function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355799/changing-image-on-jquery-toggle-function)

Comment: @mxr7350 I think that's the wrong dupe target. As this question is not about jQuery.

Comment: you can use bootstrap accordion to achieve this , you can also refer this link [example](https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/mhu8rj3e/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different classes for opened and closed status.
Then with javascript you changed that on click.

There is a working example without jQuery. You just have to include your images in the right places (content:url(...)).

[jsfiddle: change style list image without jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/tg_alfa/cxxLggqc/)

```
#ulist > li {
  list-style: none;
}
#ulist > li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
} 
#ulist > li:before {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
#ulist > li.closed:before {
  content: "+";
}
#ulist > li.opened:before {
  content: "-";
}
```